Flutter app is always running even when closed
I built a flutter app but, even when it's closed, I have the silent notification
"App is running - tap for more information or to stop the app"
The only way to remove the notification is by clicking on it to open the app info and click on "force stop"
The only package that I thought could be suspicious is "WakelockPlus" that allow the screen to stay always active but the problem occurs even if I disable it.
Does anyone faced this problem? How can I solve it?


I'm seeing the same problem now. It was working fine before. I don't know what may cause this. Did you find  any solution? Sometime I see a message of "MediaPlayer finalized without being released". I wonder if it has something to do with the AudioPlayer package that I'm using.

No, I haven't solved it yet.
I'm planning on revert the app to older commits to understand when it started, hoping to discover what caused it

I have found my issue. I forgot that I was testing a package playify which has a bug  that causes MediaPlayer finalized without being released. I removed the package and the issue is gone.

I had the same package, removing it solved the problem (now I need to replace it with something that allows me to browse iOS playlists). If you post this suggestion as an answer instead of a comment I could vote it has correct

I have found the issue. I was using a package playify which has a bug that causes MediaPlayer finalized without being released. I removed the package and the issue is gone.

May I ask you where did you find that bug?
Because I need to retrieve the audio files from the music library in iOS and Playify seems to be the only package that allows me to do that

I didn't find where the bug is since I didn't look the source code. I removed the package and the error is gone. I ended up writing my own.

Ok
Is there the possibility to have your code in a public repository so that I could look at it? It could be very helpful
:D
